# difficulty in understanding the kinect sensor changed event handlers

Tags: events, kinect

can someone please explain it to me why all these event handlers are always written like this with an += operator
like the below ones

```
          kinectSensorChooser1.KinectSensorChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(kinectSensorChooser1_KinectSensorChanged);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how you declare [event handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in C#